# Make [interact-js] a synonym of [interact.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[interact.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interact.js) is the oldest of the two, has a more complete tag wiki and the form "interact.js" is the spelling of the file you load when you use the library. It has 38 questions. **This is the tag we should keep.**

[interact-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interact-js) was created later, has a poorer tag wiki and does not correspond to any functional or official spelling of the library. It has 31 questions. This tag should become a synonym.

I cannot suggest a synonym through the GUI as I don't have a score of 5 in either tag.

I'm asking for a synonym so that: a) existing questions use only one of the two tags, b) new questions cannot use the disfavored tag anymore. The first goal could be accomplished by retagging alone but the 2nd goal requires a synonym.

Comment: Interact [interact-js] with [interact.js].  Maybe?

Comment: Even the description of interact-js starts with "**interact.js** is a [...]", lol.